# Isomorphism between sum of submodules and their direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring, let $M$ be an $A$-module, and let $M'$ and $M''$ be submodules of $M$ such that $M' \cap M'' = \{0\}$.
>
> Prove that $M' + M'' \cong M' \bigoplus M''$.

I believe I need to find two maps:

$\phi: M' + M'' \longrightarrow M' \bigoplus M''$ by $(m',m'') \longrightarrow n$ where $n \in M' \bigoplus M''$

AND

$\psi: M' \bigoplus M'' \longrightarrow M' + M''$ by $(n',n'') \longrightarrow m$ where $m \in M' + M''$.

Then I need to show that these maps are in fact inverses of each other.  I also need to use the fact that $M' \cap M'' = \{0 \}$.  So I believe that to mean $\{0 \} \in M',M''$.

Are my two maps correct?  Any hints, clues, or ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: What is **your** definition of "direct sum"? Mine is *exactly* what you wrote in the yellow zone, so I guess yours is different.

Comment: Or you could find one map, show it's surjective and has trivial kernel. USE THE FORCE...I mean, ABSTRACT ALGEBRA

Comment: @MattSamuel The force is strong with this one.

Comment: My point is,  it's hard to define a nap $M'+M''\to M'\oplus M''$, but it's easy to define a map in the other direction. For a hint, the trick is addition.

Comment: Why the down vote? I showed effort, sure it may be "dumb" to someone, but isn't that the whole point of being unclear or not understanding?

Comment: @MattSamuel So I should find a map $M' \bigoplus M'' \longrightarrow M' + M''$ thats surjective?  A module homomorphism correct?  Then showing that the kernel is trivial implies injectivity?

Comment: Right. It's the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write them differently, so it seems like we're "doing something". So we will write an element of $M_1 + M_2$ as $m_1+m_2$ with $m_1 \in M_1,m_2 \in M_2$, and an element of $M_1 \oplus M_2$ as $(m_1,m_2)$ (with the same convention).

So our map $\phi: M_1 \oplus M_2 \to M_1+M_2$, will be, surprisingly enough:

$\phi(m_1,m_2) = m_1 + m_2$.

I will take it "as obvious" that $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism (you can do this yourself, I think). To prove $\phi$ is injective, it suffices to show that if:

$m_1 + m_2 = m_1' + m_2'$, that $m_1 = m_1'$ and $m_2 = m_2'$.

If the former is true, then $m_1 - m_1' = m_2' - m_2$. Now the former difference is in $M_1$, while the latter is in $M_2$, so....

Comment: So... $ker \phi$ is trivial. This show injectivity, therefore the map is bijective.  Hence an isomorphism?

Comment: @math This answer actually avoids using the first isomorphism theorem and shows injectivity directly.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thank you for explaining!!!

Comment: @math no problem

Comment: Does this proof use the fact that $M_1 \cap M_2 = \{ 0 \}$?

Comment: Not...explicitly, but it is *strongly* hinted at in the last sentence.